# wall.post vk api, access token

Tags: vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь запостить запись на стену группы вконтакте. Создал приложение, сгенерировал токен, в результате получаю отказ, при попытке запостить запись.

[image: access_token_error]

Какой токен нужно сгенерировать, что бы подобной ошибки не было? Множество запросов попробовал, но так и не сгенерировал правильный. Только больше запутался.

Answer (score 1):

> Этот метод можно вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя, полученным в Standalone-приложении через Implicit Flow, или с использованием окна подтверждения. Требуются права доступа: wall.

Надо указать в правах access token строку wall

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]